# Get value from one function and put it into another function

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables

I need to get the value of `inputScore` currently held in the `extractVariable` function into the `assignValue` function (this function gives the value of `inputScore` to an Index.html page). I tried to store `inputScore` in a global object to solve scope issues, but inside `assignValue` the `global.scoreValue` variable is undefined. How can I get inputScore into assignValue please? New to programming - any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
global = {};


function extractVariable(inputScore) {

   global['scoreValue'] = inputScore;

};


function assignValue() { 

    document.getElementById("inputScore").value = global.scoreValue;

};
```

Thanks for everyone’s help. I am so close to solving what I need to do. The issue seems to be getting `inputScore` into the `Index.html` page. I should have posted all of my code in the first place. Apologies. `index.html` is a separate file, which has a link to the javascript file (`Game.js`). I have tested the link and it is working. When a button is pressed in `Game.js`, `index.html` loads, reads the `assignValue` function in `Game.js`, and inserts the players score (`inputScore`) into an input value in a form. At the moment all that is being inserted into the form is:
[image]
I cannot figure out why it is not working. I have included code from both files below. Any help is once again appreciated.

Game.js code:

```
function extractVariable(inputScore) {

return inputScore;


};


function assignValue(inputScore) {  
     document.getElementById("playerScore").value = inputScore;

};



var CrystalRunner = CrystalRunner || {};

CrystalRunner.GameState = {

init: function() {
  //...code here
  }, 


create: function() {
 //...code here
  },  


 update: function() {  
//..code here
//check if the player needs to die
      if(this.player.top >= this.game.world.height) {
         this.gameOver();
      }
  },  


 gameOver: function(){

    //..code here

    this.updateHighscore();

    //..code here

   },


  updateHighscore: function(){
    this.highScore = +localStorage.getItem('highScore');


    if(this.highScore < this.myScore){
            this.highScore = this.myScore;

            this.inputScore = this.highScore; 


            this.submitScoreButton = this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX-135, this.game.world.centerY+100, 'submitScoreButton');

            this.submitScoreButton.events.onInputUp.add(function() {

                    window.location.href = "index1.php"; 

              }, this);

        extractVariable(this.inputScore);
      }


      localStorage.setItem('highScore', this.highScore);
  },


};
```

Index.html code:

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Crystal Candy Game Login</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>


<body onload="assignValue(extractVariable())" class="bg"> 


    <div id="preloader">
        <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
    </div><!--preloader-->


    <div class="wrapper">


        <div id="main">

        <!-- Form -->
        <form id="form-style" method="post" action="crystalhandle.php" autocomplete="off">


                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label class="header-text"><span>First Name</span></label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="username" placeholder="Name" title="Please enter your Firstname" required="">
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label class="header-text"><span>Score</span></label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="tel" id="playerScore" name="score" value="" readonly>
                    </div>


                    <div class="w3ls-btn form-group">       
                        <div class="wthreesubmitaits">
                        <input type="submit" name="signup" id="reg" class="button" id="next1" value="Send" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;"
                        </div> 
                    </div>


        </form>


        </div>

    </div>

<div id="bodytext"></div>


     <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js'></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/phaser.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/states/Game.js"></script>

         <script>
            $(window).on('load', function() {
            $('#status').fadeOut(); 
            $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); 
            $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});


            })
    </script>

</body>


</html>
```

I have done the following changes, I think a solution is at hand. In `Index.html` I changed the following line by removing `inputScore`:

```
<body onload="assignValue(extractVariable())" class="bg"  >
```

In `Game.js` I find that if I hard code a value into the `extractVariable` function (see below), the hard coded value is passed into the `value` attribute of the `<input>` tag in `Index.html` which is what I want it to do. However, I still cannot figure out why this only works with a hard coded value?

```
function extractVariable(inputScore) {
  inputScore = 27; //hard coded value works. Why?
return inputScore; 

};


function assignValue(inputScore) {  
  console.log(inputScore); //this console.logs the hard coded value from 
  //extractVariable like it should do
     document.getElementById("playerScore").value = inputScore;

};
```

Comment: *"but inside assignValue the global.scoreValue variable is undefined"* That would happen if `assignValue` is called **before** `extractVariable`. Since you are not providing a [mcve], there is not much we can do to help. The code you posted so far is fine.

Comment: add your html too, seems to be working with your current code.

Comment: Seems to be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Are these functions on different pages (as suggested by ”this function gives the value of inputScore to an Index.html page”)?

Comment: Why just don't return that value from the `extractVariable` function?

Then you can call it in the `assignValue` and use returned value. Or If its called anywhere outside use it returned value from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved it. Here is the solution for anyone interested. I have included the Game.js code with comments to show what I did. Index.html remains as I edited it in the question. Thanks for everyone who helped.

```
    function extractVariable(inputScore) {

  inputScore = +localStorage.getItem('highScore'); //we then define inputScore again 
by getting the score stored on local storage

  return inputScore; 

};



function assignValue(inputScore) {  

     document.getElementById("playerScore").value = inputScore;

};



var CrystalRunner = CrystalRunner || {};

CrystalRunner.GameState = {

init: function() {

  },


create: function() {

  },   


update: function() {  

      if(this.player.top >= this.game.world.height && this.counter === 0 || 
 this.player.left <= 0 && this.counter === 0) {
         this.gameOver();
      }


  },     


  gameOver: function(){

          this.updateHighscore();



      var style = {font: '40px Arial', fill: '#fff'};
     this.add.text(this.game.width/2, this.game.height/4, 'GAME OVER', 
style).anchor.setTo(0.5);


      style = {font: '30px Arial', fill: '#fff'};
      this.add.text(this.game.width/2, this.game.height/4 + 50, 'High score: ' + 
this.highScore, style).anchor.setTo(0.5);

      this.add.text(this.game.width/2, this.game.height/4 + 80, 'Your score: ' + 
this.myScore, style).anchor.setTo(0.5);

      style = {font: '18px Arial', fill: '#fff'};
      this.add.text(this.game.width/2, this.game.height/4 + 120, 'Tap/click to play 
again', style).anchor.setTo(0.5);


      this.game.input.onDown.addOnce(this.restart, this);


    }, this);

    gameOverPanel.start();
    this.counter++;

  },


  restart: function(){

    this.game.state.start('Game');
  },

  updateHighscore: function(){
    this.highScore = +localStorage.getItem('highScore');


    if(this.highScore < this.myScore){
            this.highScore = this.myScore;

      localStorage.setItem('highScore', this.highScore);

      this.inputScore= +localStorage.getItem('highScore'); //this input.Score needs 
      //to get it's value from localStorage and not this.highScore


            this.submitScoreButton = this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX- 
   135, this.game.world.centerY+100, 'submitScoreButton');
            this.submitScoreButton.inputEnabled = true;
            this.submitScoreButton.fixedToCamera = true;

            extractVariable(this.inputScore); //call extractVariable

            this.submitScoreButton.events.onInputDown.add(function() {


                        window.location.href = "index1.php";


                  }, this);

            }

       },


};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by returning the value from `extractVariable` and then passing it in as a parameter into `assignValue`:

```
function extractVariable(inputScore) {
  return inputScore;
};


function assignValue(inputScore) {
  document.getElementById("inputScore").value = inputScore;
};

assignValue(extractVariable(inputScore));
```

Comment: Nitpick: this is not what function composition is. Function composition creates a new function.

Comment: Ah, could I call it composite functions or still no...?

Comment: To be honest, idk. You are just passing the return value of one function to the next function. Not sure this has a special name `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. I've editted my answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to call or invoke *extractVariable()* inside *assignValue()*

```js
var global = {};
function extractVariable(inputScore) {
   global['scoreValue'] = inputScore;
};
function assignValue() {
  extractVariable('test');
  document.getElementById("inputScore").value = global.scoreValue;
};
assignValue();
```

```html
<input id="inputScore"/>
```

Though it is not necessary to use the variable in this case, you can simply return the value from the function:

```js
function extractVariable(inputScore) {
   return inputScore;
};
function assignValue(input) {
  document.getElementById("inputScore").value = input;
};
assignValue(extractVariable('test'));
```

```html
<input id="inputScore"/>
```

Comment: If that was possible, then `extractVariable` should just return the value instead of using a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Please use es6 and scoping with let - here is an example that works fine:

```
let scoreValue = 0;

function extractVariable(inputScore) {

    scoreValue = inputScore;

};

function assignValue() {

    console.log(scoreValue);

};

extractVariable(200);
assignValue();
```

Comment: Hello Sebastian, I appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks so much. Not sure who downvoted you, certainly wasn't me!

Comment: no Probs - since a few weeks downvotes increase --- programming is not a linear thing - you can reach your goal in a thousand ways. I try to give answers that match to the way you walked - for me - your case looks like a form-application so I would use a JS framework to handle all the stuff, writing classes and so on - but perhaps this is too much for the case you exactly need - so I tried to give you "hints" to solve your current architecture ... keep on coding ;)

Comment: and by the waym you can call function in a function the same way - when you use the right scoping: assignValue(extractVariable(200)); works ;)

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I have edited my question by adding more code and have explained what I am trying to do more clearly. I should have done that in the first place. Nonetheless, I am much closer to solving this thanks to everyone's help so far.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot figure out why it is not working.

[The `id`s of HTML elements become global variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)

You have an element with `id` `inputScore`.

You are specifying that `extractVariable` should be called with `inputScore` as argument:

```
<body onload="assignValue(extractVariable(inputScore))" class="bg">
```

Thus you are trying to set the a DOM element to be the value of a text input. That cannot work. The string representation of a DOM element is exactly what you are seeing in your screenshot

```js
console.log(document.createElement('span').toString());
```

---

It's not clear to me what you expect `inputScore` to refer to here. So the only suggestion I can give is to remove the `onload` handler.

Comment: Thank so much Felix for your response. I had no idea about HTML element ids being global variables. I have changed the input id to `playerScore`. The `inputScore` parameter in the `assignValue` function being called `onload` in the`index.html` file is referencing the parameter used in `extractVariable(inputScore)` in the `Game.js` file. I do not know if this needs to be there though. index.html keeps telling me that `inputScore` is undefined. All I need is for the value returned to `extractVariable(inputScore)` in Game.js to be put into the value of the input tag in `index.html`.

Comment: Well, the browser is right, there is no variable `inputScore` in global scope when the page loads. What do you expect the value to be at page load? Or in other words: Which value do you want to show in the input field at page load. If the input field should *initially* be empty, just remove the call.

Comment: Hi Felix, I have done some edits to my question explaining where I am now at. I have removed `inputscore` from the call in `index.js` as you suggested. Thanks for your help on that. If find that if I hard-code a value into `inputScore` in `Game.js` the code now works. If I don't hard code a value then it doesn't. Any idea why? `extractVariable` in `Game.js` is definitely getting a value because it console.logs one.